# Business cards: Cannot save according to Illustrator template

Tags: adobe-illustrator, business

I want to make a business card in illustrator.
Here is my design:
[image]
Question 1:
The design labeled (1) is perfectly aligned from back to front.
I've downloaded a template for illustrator [here](http://www.overnightprints.co.uk/main.php?A=specs_show&W=illustrator).

The problem is when I export as tiff, the image doesn't follow the guides, the lines that  are already in illustrator. Instead, it saves the whole image, I mean they didn't cut just until bleed line, or am I misunderstanding something?

Question 2:
If I want to print there and to have it perfectly match the design labeled (1) I must follow [this](http://www.overnightprints.co.uk/main.php?A=orientation_v&S=vss) right? So do I have to make the design in illustrator like the design labeled (2)? I'm having a difficult time matching these up.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the second example which you linked, they have an graphic which suggests a vertical card which "attaches" the front and back on a side edge and "folds" left-to-right, *but* the example they give for you to follow for actual submission shows the card with the "top" marked: imagine the logical bottom edge of the card is attached and folded.

The template they give you is for a single side. The simplest way to submit the card would be to make two copies of the template. One named "front" and one named "back". The front would have the top of the card at left (rotate the card counter- or anti-clockwise), the back of the card would have the top of the card at right (rotated clockwise).

Do not export the card, submit the AI file(s). EDIT: export to PDF to ensure typefaces etc. are properly included in the submission.

Comment: Just to note, the template page lists PDF as an acceptable format, but not AI.

Comment: Right, if exported correctly, PDF would embed typefaces etc.

Comment: Overnight prints actually work best with AI8 EPS if possible, then PDF/X-1a from my experience.

Comment: I was trying to keep it simple :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand all of the question, but for a start, if you are working in Illustrator, which is a vector application, don't export as TIFF, which is pixel-based format, export as PDF.

It's very difficult to follow your layout examples because the lack of text and the simple design makes it difficult to determine orientation.

The [printer's example](http://www.overnightprints.co.uk/main.php?A=orientation_v&S=vss), which includes text, should make it quite clear what they expect.

I would put a line of text (e.g. FRONT/BACK) on each side of your card design, work it through, and then add some new example iamges into your question if you still need help.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I managed to export as pdf but I still want a png version for review, want the image to cut exactly at the bleed point, another question, did my orientation correct? I think it is

Comment: I can't tell, as I said your examples are difficult to follow

Comment: ? nvm but how to export as PNG following the trim line as I save in pdf?

Answer (score 2):

I think part of your issue is 'crop to artboard' -- make sure that option is checked.

But, as e100 said, you should really be saving as PDF anyway, not exporting to tiff. The PDF will honor your artboard without tossing out the art beyond it, just in case.